# problema com javascript os inputs não chamam a função?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Estou com um problema no meu código, precisava fazer um campo de pesquisa só que me deparei com um problema os campos inputs ignora a função javascript e jquery e no caso dos inputs submit nem atualizar a página meu código é o seguinte:

//parte javascript:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $('#bs-mrb').on('keyup',function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
//          if($('#bs-prod').val() != "") {
                var dato = $('#bs-mrb').val();
                var x = $('#str').val();
                var url = x+'_functions.php?action=buscaMrb';
//              alert("dato: "+dato+" x: "+x+" url: "+url);
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:url,
                    data:'dato='+dato,
                    success: function(datos){
                        $('#agrega-registros').html(datos);
                        r1 = tooltip();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
//      }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

//parte HTML:

```
<body onLoad="tooltip();">
<?php
$funcao = $_REQUEST["op"];

if (function_exists($funcao)) {
    call_user_func($funcao);
}

function saida() {
titulo("FA - saída","course.png")  ?>
    <section>
    <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
         <td>
           <input type="hidden" name="str" id="str" value="aqm"/>
         </td>
    <form name="frm_pesq" method="post" action="">
         <td width="300">

<input type="text" placeholder="ID / PartNumber / SN Item" name="pesq" size="25" id="bs-mrb">
            <input type="hidden" name="str" id="str" value="fa"/>
         </td>
    </form>
       </tr>
   </table>
</section>

<div class="registros" id="agrega-registros">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover nowrap">
            <thead class="head">

                <th nowrap width="10px">Status</th>
                <th nowrap width="50px">ID</th>
                <th nowrap width="160px">DataEntrada</th>
                <th nowrap width="120px">PartNumber</th>
                <th nowrap width="140px">SNItem</th>
                <th nowrap width="140px">Description</th>
                <th nowrap width="150px">Defect</th>
                <th nowrap width="150px">TransferOrder</th>
                <th nowrap width="10px">teste</th>
            </thead>
            <?php 
                    aqui vai a query select * from tabela; 
                    e trás as informações do banco.
                      após isso fecho a função saída();
             } ?>

             </table>
            </div>
```

No campo input `id="bs-mrb"` não chama nenhuma função já tentei javascript e jquery não funciona só reconheceu um `alert();` colocando dentro do input por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" value="pesquisar" id="bs-mrb" onkeypress="alert('teste');">
```

Assim funcionou mais se eu colocar um alert em uma função não funciona alguém pode me ajudar nisso.

Detalhe minha query está funcionando o problema é só na chamada da função javascript no input e também já tentei fazer um onsubmit dentro do formulário e não funcionou e também esta pagina estou chamando dentro de uma  de outra pagina index.

com o codigo abaixo:

//javascript que chama a pagina acima.

```
<script>
function display_c(){
    setInterval('getInfo()',30000);
}
function getInfo(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("conteudo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "MRB_Dados.php?op=<?php echo $op;?>", true);
    xmlhttp.send('conteudo');
}
</script>
```

//e a parte html que recebe a pagina acima dentro da div conteúdo.

```
<body onload="display_c(); getInfo('<?php echo $op ; ?>');">
<div id="header">
<div id="masthead_upper" class="masthead full fullwidth">
  <div class="container_20">
    <div class="grid_6" id="logo"> <a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>/coffe/mrb.php?op=<?php echo $op;?>">Lenovo</a> </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;color:white;font-family:Arial;font-size:32px;top:15px; right:20px; text-align: right;">Controle</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;color:white;font-family:Arial;font-size:10px;top:48px; right:20px; text-align: right;">Developed by Engineering System</div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:65px; left:10px; text-align: left;">
    <nav class="grid_20 cf" id="menus"> 
        <ul class="fullwidth" id="navigation"><br>
          <li class="first" id="laptops"><font color="#FFCC00" face="verdana" size="2"><b><?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['usuario'])." - ".strtoupper($_SESSION['nome']);?></b></font>
            <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['usuario'])) { ?> 
                <font color="#FFCC00" face="verdana" size="2"><?php echo " - ".strtoupper($_SESSION['depto']);?>|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="color: #fff;" href="logout.php">[logout]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="countDown" style="color:white"></span></font>
            <?php } ?>  
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>      
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<!-- begin: Main Grid -->
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="landingcontent"><br />
        <table width="100%" height="100%" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="columnR" width="87%" valign="top" align="left">
            <!-- inicio td -->
                <div id="conteudo"></div>
            <!-- fim td -->      

          </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- end: Main Grid -->
<!-- begin: Footer -->
<?php // include "footer.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ele ignora porque espera você pressionar a tecla enter para então efetuar a pesquisa:

```
if(e.which == 13) {

}
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  
    $('#bs-mrb').on('keyup',function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
//          if($('#bs-prod').val() != "") {
                var dato = $('#bs-mrb').val();
                var x = $('#str').val();
                var url = x+'_functions.php?action=buscaMrb';
//              alert("dato: "+dato+" x: "+x+" url: "+url);
          
          alert("Pesquisando...")
          
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:url,
                    data:'dato='+dato,
                    success: function(datos){
                        alert('Retorno pesquisa: ' + datos)
                    },
                  error: function(error){
                   alert('Erro pesquisa: ' + error.statusText)
                  }
                });
                return false;
            }
//      }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
         <td>
           <input type="hidden" name="str" id="str" value="aqm"/>
         </td>
    <form name="frm_pesq" method="post" action="">
         <td width="300">

<input type="text" placeholder="ID / PartNumber / SN Item" name="pesq" size="25" id="bs-mrb">
            <input type="hidden" name="str" id="str" value="fa"/>
         </td>
    </form>
       </tr>
   </table>
</section>

<div class="registros" id="agrega-registros">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover nowrap">
            <thead class="head">

                <th nowrap width="10px">Status</th>
                <th nowrap width="50px">ID</th>
                <th nowrap width="160px">DataEntrada</th>
                <th nowrap width="120px">PartNumber</th>
                <th nowrap width="140px">SNItem</th>
                <th nowrap width="140px">Description</th>
                <th nowrap width="150px">Defect</th>
                <th nowrap width="150px">TransferOrder</th>
                <th nowrap width="10px">teste</th>
            </thead>

             </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Emir eu fiz uns testes aqui o submit não funciona porque a pagina que está sendo executada dentro de uma <div> de outra pagina testei fora funciona

Comment: Está pouco confuso sua pergunta. Você quer dar um submit ccom botão ou usar ajax com jquery?